# How do I use animate and addclass together

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, addclass

I'm trying to animate an element in my page. I'm looking for a kind of zoom in effect with a click condition. You click a div and that div becomes the page.

I get the animate to work. However the addClass function doesn't work.

I'm also using a scrolling for my elements that are scrolled by the user or automated. So the div that control scrolling are faded over my actual elements. When I click an element to animate it it works. It gets wider and higher but I can't work the position and z-index. So I tried to add an addClass function to work it out but it doesn't work!?

Here's my code

```
$("#bloc1").live('click', function(){
    $("#bloc1").animate({
        width: "800px",
        margin: "0px",
        height: "100%",
    },3000);

    $('#bloc1').addClass('figureclick');  
});
```

You can also try it ou here [test page](http://zed.no-ip.org) Click on "le block 1" to see the effect

Thank you for your support!

UPDATE !!

I am not using a div im using HTML5 CSS3 and they are just plain figure /figure tags
and my css goes like #container figure{}

Would it prevent the addclass to work?

Comment: well it did zoom for me..what's the problem again? and please fix your code formatting

Comment: The zoom is part of the animate but the z-index isnt working and is from the addClass

Answer (score 2):

The syntax highlighting tells all - you need to remove the escaping backslashes. `.live()` also only takes one function, so combine the two into the same function:

```
$("#bloc1").live('click', function(){
    $("#bloc1").animate({
        width: "800px",
        margin: "0px",
        height: "100%",
    },3000);

    $('#bloc1').addClass('figureclick');  
});
```

Comment: The escaping slashes are there becuse i use php and i clean it out before posting and forgot them. Is there any other reason why this wouldnt work?  By the way im using css 3  so its not a dive its just a <figure></figure>  and the css goes like #container figure{} ive added a class to it and it still doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you have the nested functions or the escaping slashes. you should be able to do this...

```
$("#bloc1").live( 'click', function() {
  $(this).animate({
    width: "800px",
    margin: "0px",
    height: "100%"
  },3000 ).addClass('figureclick') ; 
});
```

Comment: The escaping slashes are there becuse i use php and i clean it out before posting and forgot them. Is there any other reason why this wouldnt work?  By the way im using css 3  so its not a dive its just a <figure></figure>  and the css goes like #container figure{} ive added a class to it and it still doesnt work

Comment: The 2nd parameter needs to be a anonymous or named function. This won't work.

Comment: Well i got it to work by changing my figure tags by div tags but i dont want a div

Comment: what browser are you testing in?

Comment: Scott is correct my syntax was missing the anonymous function declaration, i've updated my example.

Comment: Im using all browsers but devloping with Chrome

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with your trailing comma after the animate options. This will cause issues in IE.

Also, you can make use of chaining as below.

```
$("#bloc1").live('click', function(){
    $(this).animate({
        width: "800px",
        margin: "0px",
        height: "100%"
    },3000).addClass('figureclick'); 
});
```

And finally, if you want to add the class after the animation is complete you can use a callback function like the following:

```
$("#bloc1").live('click', function(){
    $(this).animate({width: "800px", margin: "0px", height: "100%"}, 3000, function() {
      $(this).addClass('figureclick');
    });
});
```

Comment: Still the same! Actualy its not that it doesnt work. It kinda work. However the addClass isnt working unless i make my element a div if i use html5 tags it doesnt work! Thanks for helping tho!